# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@userID' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

O erro é o que está no título, conversão char para int. "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@userID' to data type int." Agradeço qualquer ajuda e se tiverem alguma dica de boas práticas, é ainda melhor, porque sou novo nisto e estou aprendendo sozinho. Obrigado pela atenção

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Save_Recipe
(@userID int,
@recipeName nvarchar(50),
@recipeDuration nvarchar(50),
@recipeDificultyID int,
@recipePreparation nvarchar(MAX))
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO [Taverna_Da_Esquina].[dbo].[Recipe] ([userID],[recipeName],[recipeDuration],[recipeDificultyID],[recipePreparation])
OUTPUT inserted.[recipeID]
VALUES (@userID,@recipeName,@recipeDuration,@recipeDificultyID,@recipePreparation)
END

EXECUTE Save_Recipe 1,nome,duracao,1,preparacao
```

**Resulta no erro:**

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '@userID' to data
>   type int.

Esse é o código C# da minha aplicação:

```
public void Save(Recipe recipe)
{

conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Save_Recipe",conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@userID", recipe.UserID));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@recipeName", recipe.RecipeName));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@recipeDuration",recipe.RecipeDuration));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@recipeDificultyID", recipe.RecipeDificultyID));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@recipePreparation", recipe.RecipePreparation));

try
{

conn.Open();
int receitaID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

//Associar os ingredientes à receita
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Recipe_AddIngredientList",conn);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@recipeID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ingredientID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@quantity", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@measureID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);

foreach (Ingredient i in recipe.RecipeListIngredientes)
{
cmd2.Parameters["@recipe_id"].Value = receitaID;
cmd2.Parameters["@ingredient_id"].Value = i.IngredientID;
cmd2.Parameters["@quantity"].Value = i.IngredientQuantity;
cmd2.Parameters["@medida"].Value = i.IngredientMeasureID;
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Traduza a pergunta, aqui é o **[pt.stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)** ;)

Comment: Não tinha reparado que esta secção era portuguesa. Meu erro obrigado :D

Comment: Veja se na sua Classe `Recipe` a propriedade `.UserID` é do tipo `string`... Se for basta modifica para `int` - e se atentar de usar o `Convert.ToInt32()` na hora de alimentar a propriedade, pois caso seja um `string`, provavelmente esta sendo alimentada por uma `string`.